# How to order controls from a pre-determined order

Tags: jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, controls, ascx

I have registered some controls on a page and set their public properties server side no problem so they display as intended. Now there is a requirement to set the order of the controls on page load dynamically from ordering values saved in a database table. As per the code shown on the ascx page the ordering is currently static and sequential. Is there a way to set the order based on the database ordering values either from the server or using jQuery etc?

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <controls:PrintMDTHeader ID="PrintMDTHeader1" runat="server" />
      <controls:PrintMDTStaging ID="PrintMDTStaging1" runat="server" />
      <controls:PrintMDTPresentation ID="PrintMDTPresentation1" runat="server" />
      <controls:PrintMDTInvestigation ID="PrintMDTInvestigation1" runat="server" />
      <controls:PrintMDTDiagnosis ID="PrintMDTDiagnosis1" runat="server" />
      <controls:PrintMDTNonPrimary ID="PrintMDTNonPrimary1" runat="server" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't think of this but

```
<asp:PlaceHolder />
```

fits the bill nicely